# Highlighting cells which move after auto sort

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, conditional-formatting

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DNOVUGPAJF-nR9XtQ1fc-lqm4fYHNBJgz7-rr6SzJaU/edit?usp=sharing

In the above test SS, I have a league table in range `J20:N22` which has an auto sort in place. To see this, click on the Full House checkbox in Player 1's scoring section at the top and this will add a further 5 points to their score and see them move above Player 2 in the league.

What I would like is some sort of conditional formatting based on if a player moves up or down in the league - maybe a red colour if they move down and a green if they move up. So in the example of adding the 5 points to Player 1 used above, Player 1 would move to the top of the league and would be coloured green to indicate a move upwards and Player 2 would receive a red colour to indicate a move downwards.

Is this possible as I am struggling to find any info relating to this via Google searches as all it draws up is creating a sort based on colours which is obviously not what I am looking at?

Thanks

Comment: You need to store the previous position somewhere so that CF can detect the change.

Comment: Since this tab is labelled Wk 11, assuming you have other tabs for the previous weeks, you could make this work.  If you kept a summary sheet, that basically had each player, their points for each week, and their current league position, then on the summary you could track whether they were "red" or "green" for a current week.  This could then also be reflected back to each weekly sheet, if you wanted.   If you try this approach, let us know if you run into any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be able to share a picture, I'll throw this up as a possible answer.

Assuming that you can do some form of summary table, by week, it could look something like the following.  You could add or exclude or hide any columns you like.

[image]

You can see Player 2 moved up, and green in Week 2, while Player 3 dropped.  No change in ranks in Week 3, but changes again in Week 4.

The conditional formatting rule I used (this one for green) was:

```
=G3<offset(G3,0,-3)
```

For red, just reverse the < symbol to greater than, >.

Note that it is important to get the right range selected for the conditional formatting formula.  In my case, G3:G10, J3:J10,M3:M10.  The lower rows don't matter, but the columns and the starting row do.

This is applied to the column which holds each weeks rank.  It just compares that week's rank, for each player, against their previous rank, three columns back.  If it is less than, they've gone up in rank, and get shown as green.

And if you wanted to show the current state on each weekly tab, you could just copy the corresponding week's ranking column, and the previous week's and check the change in rankings to apply the red or green on each week's mini-table of results.

Let us know if this helps, or if you are looking for something different.

Comment: If you want this done on your weekly sheets, please add a couple of extra tabs for previous weeks, and a few more players, to make it clearer what is changing from week to week, and what you would like to see shown.